# How to displays all photos from album using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJs application with photo albums, at the first step i load all photos from server when user come to site:

```
 logicOfMyApp.getPhotosFromServerFunc().then(function (photos) {
    if (photos.length != 0) {
        $scope.photosArray = photos;
        console.log($scope.photosArray);
    }
 });
```

At the AlbumsPage.html i display title and cover of album:

```
<div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="itm in albumsArray">
    <a ng-click="followToAlbum(itm.id)" href=""> {{itm.title}}</a><br />
    <img ng-src="../Files/{{itm.pathToCover}}" width="250px" height="160px" class="img-rounded" />
</div>
```

after click to title of album i send id of clicked album to `followToAlbum(itm.id)` method where i get all photos and redirect to album page:

```
 $scope.followToAlbum = function (id) {
    $scope.AllPhotosOfSingleAlbum = logicOfMyApp.getPhotoOfAlbumFunc($scope.photosArray, id);
    console.log($scope.AllPhotosOfSingleAlbum);
    $location.path('/albums/' + id);
};
```

i get all photos of album by id but it doesn't dipslay.
[image]

I created at the empty $scope.AllPhotosOfSingleAlbum  im my controller:

```
$scope.AllPhotosOfSingleAlbum = [];
```

Here the source code of my method where i get photos of album:

```
getPhotoOfAlbumFunc: function (photosArray, albumIdRoute) {
        var allPhotosOfAlbum = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < photosArray.length; i++) {
            if (photosArray[i].albumId == albumIdRoute) {
                allPhotosOfAlbum.push(photosArray[i]);
            }
        }

        return allPhotosOfAlbum;
    }
```

Maybe somebody knows how i can resolve it ? Thanks for your answers !

Comment: Try creating the $scope.photosArray as an empty array in your controller first then in the callback loop over the photos and push() them into the $scope.photosArray

Comment: @LazyCoder thanks for your answer, oh , I forget.. I done it, I'll edit my post and add method where I get photos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define a new ng-repeat for photos. When `AllPhotosOfSingleAlbum` changes photos will be opened.

Add these to your html code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 photos-area">
    <div class="col-xs-4 photo-area"  ng-repeat="photo_item in AllPhotosOfSingleAlbum">
        <img ng-src="../Files/{{photo_item.path}}" width="250px" height="160px" class="img-rounded" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh, how i can change array ? i tried use reverse(), and $scope.AllPhotosOfSingleAlbum[0]= "" - but it doesn't help. Sir, do you have an idea how i can change my array ?

Comment: @VladimirKhodakovskey Does followToAlbum() function change your array?

Comment: @VladimirKhodakovskey no problem. If i helped you can u apply my answer.